# Anyway to see in IE 8 Developer Tools the list of the .js associated with a page?

Tags: javascript, ie-developer-tools

anyway to see in IE 8 Developer Tools the list of the .js associated with a page?

In the same way as in Firebug.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 'Script' tab there's a select list next to the 'Start debugging' button, that lists all the loaded resources.